# Subset and lookup from separate table

Tags: r, subset, grepl

I have this lookup DATA FRAME:

```
  VAR1=c('X1')
  VAR2=c('X2')
  VAR3=c('X3')
  VAR4=c('X4')
  VAR5=c('NA')

  df<-data.frame(VAR1,VAR2,VAR3,VAR4,VAR5)
```

which I need to cross reference with a main DATA FRAME so that I select variables X1 to X5. Sometimes, like the example, column 5 is simply NA.

I would typically use something like the below:

```
 main_data <-subset(main_data, select=c(df[1,1],df[1,2],df[1,3]))

 main_data <-subset(main_data, select=c(df[1,1:max(col(df))]))
```

but there are NAs, and moreover I will have a dynamic count of columns and these don't work.

The other idea is to use grepl on main_data but I cannot get it to work with more than one variable at a time:

```
 main_data <- main_data[, grepl(paste0(df[1:max(col(df))], colnames(main_data)))]
```

I am certain there is a straightforward way to do this but I cannot find it.

Comment: Another way would be to coerce `df` to vector and use `%in%`. E.g. `main_data[, names(main_data) %in% yourvector]`.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Good point, I am testing this one out now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Roman's help I got it:

```
  df<-as.vector(unlist(df))
  main_data<-main_data[, names(main_data) %in% df]
```